# JS/JQuery Does onBlur fire when focused on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a question regarding the onBlur DOM event. I was wondering if I set an onBlur event handler on a div. Does it fire if I focus on a child element inside of that div. I want to submit an ajax request to an MVC controller when a div containing all the necessary input elements handles the onBlur event.

Also this would be saving a list of entities related to the main model (in a partial view) which may either be an edit or a create. I would test this out myself, but I still need to set up the controller action and move my markup to a partial view.

Comment: It's such a basic thing to try this and find out.

Comment: Events bubble to parents unless they are stopped with `stopPropagation` (stop bubbling) or `stopImmediatePropagation` (stop bubbling + don't execute any other handlers bound to the element).

Comment: Div elements do not trigger a blur event.  Only elements that can be focused will trigger that event.

Comment: JQuery allows you to add a handler on blur for just about anything nowadays (at least on the more recent browsers). Think of it like when you're on youtube & hit the space bar to pause. If you aren't focused on that element where the video plays, it will just scroll down a bunch.

Comment: I will get onto testing this myself now, I was wanting to make sure what I was planning was do-able before I commit too much to something that wouldn't work. I'm almost to the point where I can test this on the view so I'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will fire on the container event, because of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing), unless a listener on an element calls `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling further.

But this event doesn't mean you left the DIV. E.g. if you have HTML like:

```
<div>
    <input name="in1" type="text">
    <input name="in2" type="text">
</div>
```

If you go from `in1` to `in2` a `blur` event will be triggered on `in1`. This event will bubble out to the DIV as well.

If you want to detect a click outside the DIV, see [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful with my planning. I was also trying to figure out if you clicked/focused on an text box inside of a parent div. Would that parent div dispatch the Blur event still? Or would it still technically be focused on since the user would be focused on a child element inside of the parent. My goal is to send an ajax call whenever the user is done inputting data and clicks outside of the form/parent div. Saving it without the need of a button as a requirement for a project.

Comment: Any time you change the focused element, a `blur` event is triggered. It doesn't matter what the new focused element is.